# Assigning one column of dataframe to column of another dataframe with disparate indices?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have dataframes `first` and `second` of the same length, where the first one's index is increments of 15 and the second is in increments of 1. I would like to assign one column of `first` to another of `second`.

e.g., something like below

```
import pandas as pd

first = pd.DataFrame({"index": [0, 15, 30], "value": [2.2, 2.2, 2.2]})
second = pd.DataFrame({"value": [3.2, 3.2, 3.2]})
first = first.set_index("index")
first.value = second.value
```

however, the indices are disparate so the above gives `NaN`s for `first.value` after the first row. I think one approach is to call `reset_index()` prior to assignment, but I believe this is a costly op? Is there an approach that doesn't involve resetting the index?

Answer (score 2):

IIUC, you can assign numpy array to dataframe column

```py
first['value'] = second['value'].values
# or
first['value'] = second['value'].to_numpy()
```

```
print(first)

       value
index
0        3.2
15       3.2
30       3.2
```

Comment: ah I see, but is calling `values` or `to_numpy()` more costly than `reset_index()`?

Comment: @roulette01 It won't, `values` wipes index from Series while `reset_index()` involves index and column conversion.